# javascript merge two arrays with custom key

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have two array with custom key but when i want to merge them JavaScript return emtpy array.

```js
let x = [];
x['a'] = 1;

let y = [];
y['b'] = 2;

console.log(x.concat(y));
console.log([...x, ...y]);
```

There is any way to use JavaScript function two merge them or i have to use `for` and iterate all items??

Comment: `let y = []; y['b'] = 2` results in an array with a property with the key `'b'` and the value `2`. `concat` and `...` only consider properties with integral keys. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish as I doubt you are using the correct data structures.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you for your comment. I understand that i should use Object for my case when i read your notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you use string value as an array key. Which is not allowed in JavaScript. If you want string as a key you need to use 'object' instead of array.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but it _absolutely is_ allowed they just aren't considered elements of the array, rather they are treated like `length`. It is usually best avoided however.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using arrays like Object, use `Object.keys`. (Object.values and Object.entries)

```js
let x = [];
x['a'] = 1;

let y = [];
y['b'] = 2;

console.log(x.concat(y));
console.log([...x, ...y]);

console.log([...Object.keys(x), ...Object.keys(y)]);
console.log([...Object.values(x), ...Object.values(y)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge this with using object try this:

```js
let x = [{}];
x[0]['a'] = 1;

let y = [{}];
y[0]['b'] = 2;

console.log(x.concat(y));
```